# How to add global exception interceptor in gRPC server?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

In gRPC , how to add a global exception interceptor that intercepts any `RuntimeException` and propagate meaningful information to the client ?

for example , a `divide` method may throw `ArithmeticException` with `/ by zero` message . In the server side , I may write :

```
@Override
public void divide(DivideRequest request, StreamObserver<DivideResponse> responseObserver) {
  int dom = request.getDenominator();
  int num = request.getNumerator();

  double result = num / dom;
  responseObserver.onNext(DivideResponse.newBuilder().setValue(result).build());
  responseObserver.onCompleted();
}
```

If the client passes denominator = 0 , it will get :

```
Exception in thread "main" io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN
```

And the server outputs

```
Exception while executing runnable io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$2@62e95ade
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

The client doesn't know what's going on.

If I want to pass `/ by zero` message to client , I have to modify server to :
(as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810657/exception-handling-in-grpc) )

```
  try {
    double result = num / dom;
    responseObserver.onNext(DivideResponse.newBuilder().setValue(result).build());
    responseObserver.onCompleted();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("onError : {}" , e.getMessage());
    responseObserver.onError(new StatusRuntimeException(Status.INTERNAL.withDescription(e.getMessage())));
  }
```

And if client sends denominator = 0 , it will get :

```
Exception in thread "main" io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: / by zero
```

Good , `/ by zero` is passed to client.

But the problem is , in a truly enterprise environment, there will be a lot of `RuntimeException`s , and if I want to pass these exception's messages to client , I will have to try catch each method , which is very cumbersome.

Is there any global interceptor that intercepts every method , catching `RuntimeException` and trigger `onError` and propagate the error message to client ? So that I don't have to deal with `RuntimeException`s in my server code .

Thanks a lot !

Note :

```
<grpc.version>1.0.1</grpc.version>
com.google.protobuf:proton:3.1.0
io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.0.1
```

Answer (score 11):

Below code will catch all runtime exceptions, Also refer the link https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/1552

```
public class GlobalGrpcExceptionHandler implements ServerInterceptor {

   @Override
   public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
         Metadata requestHeaders, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
      ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> delegate = next.startCall(call, requestHeaders);
      return new SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<ReqT>(delegate) {
         @Override
         public void onHalfClose() {
            try {
               super.onHalfClose();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               call.close(Status.INTERNAL
                .withCause (e)
                .withDescription("error message"), new Metadata());
            }
         }
      };
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to catch exceptions in **all gRPC endpoints** (including the ones processing client *streams*) **and interceptors**, you probably want something similar to the following:

```
import io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener;
import io.grpc.Metadata;
import io.grpc.ServerCall;
import io.grpc.ServerCallHandler;
import io.grpc.ServerInterceptor;
import io.grpc.Status;

public class GlobalGrpcExceptionHandler implements ServerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> serverCall,
                                                                 Metadata requestHeaders,
                                                                 ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> serverCallHandler) {
        try {
            ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> delegate = serverCallHandler.startCall(serverCall, requestHeaders);
            return new ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<ReqT>(delegate) {
                @Override
                public void onMessage(ReqT message) {
                    try {
                        super.onMessage(message); // Here onNext is called (in case of client streams)
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        handleEndpointException(e, serverCall);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onHalfClose() {
                    try {
                        super.onHalfClose(); // Here onCompleted is called (in case of client streams)
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        handleEndpointException(e, serverCall);
                    }
                }
            };
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            return handleInterceptorException(t, serverCall);
        }
    }

    private <ReqT, RespT> void handleEndpointException(Throwable t, ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> serverCall) {
        serverCall.close(Status.INTERNAL
                         .withCause(t)
                         .withDescription("An exception occurred in the endpoint implementation"), new Metadata());
    }

    private <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> handleInterceptorException(Throwable t, ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> serverCall) {
        serverCall.close(Status.INTERNAL
                         .withCause(t)
                         .withDescription("An exception occurred in a **subsequent** interceptor"), new Metadata());

        return new ServerCall.Listener<ReqT>() {
            // no-op
        };
    }
}
```

DISCLAIMER: I have gathered this by inspecting the implementation, I have not read it in the documentation and I'm not sure if it will change. For reference, I'm referring to `io.grpc` version `1.30`.

Answer (score 3):

[TransmitStatusRuntimeExceptionInterceptor](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/util/TransmitStatusRuntimeExceptionInterceptor.java) is very similar to what you want, except that it only catches `StatusRuntimeException`. You can fork it and make it catch all exceptions.

To install an interceptor for all services on a server, you can use [`ServerBuilder.intercept()`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v1.5.0/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/ServerBuilder.java#L101), which was added in gRPC 1.5.0

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin, you have to [structure your ServerInterceptor differently](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-kotlin/issues/141#issuecomment-696443611). I was using grpc-kotlin in Micronaut and the exceptions never appeared in the `SimpleForwardingServerCallListener` `onHalfClose` or other handlers.

Answer (score 2):

If you can convert your gRPC server application to spring boot using [yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter), then you can write @GrpcAdvice, similar to Spring Boot @ControllerAdvice as

```
    @GrpcAdvice
    public class ExceptionHandler {
    
      @GrpcExceptionHandler(ValidationErrorException.class)
      public StatusRuntimeException handleValidationError(ValidationErrorException cause) {
    
         Status.INVALID_ARGUMENT.withDescription("Invalid Argument")
            .asRuntimeException()
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the grpc java [examples](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/header) for interceptor?

So in my case, we use code and message as standard for defining what kind of error the server sent onto client.

Examples: server send response like

```
{
  code: 409,
  message: 'Id xxx aldready exist'
}
```

So in the client you can setup client interceptor for getting that code and response with Reflection. Fyi we use [Lognet Spring Boot starter for grpc](https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter) as the server, and Spring boot for the client.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GrpcExceptionHandler implements ServerInterceptor {

private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger (GrpcExceptionHandler.class);

@Override
public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall (ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
                                                              Metadata headers,
                                                              ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
    logger.info ("GRPC call at: {}", Instant.now ());
    ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> listener;

    try {
        listener = next.startCall (call, headers);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        logger.error ("Uncaught exception from grpc service");
        call.close (Status.INTERNAL
                .withCause (ex)
                .withDescription ("Uncaught exception from grpc service"), null);
        return new ServerCall.Listener<ReqT>() {};
    }

    return listener;
}
```

}

Sample interceptor above.

You need to bootstrap it, of course, before expecting anything from it;

```
serverBuilder.addService (ServerInterceptors.intercept (bindableService, interceptor));
```

**UPDATE**

```
public interface ServerCallHandler<RequestT, ResponseT> {
  /**
   * Produce a non-{@code null} listener for the incoming call. Implementations are free to call
   * methods on {@code call} before this method has returned.
   *
   * <p>If the implementation throws an exception, {@code call} will be closed with an error.
   * Implementations must not throw an exception if they started processing that may use {@code
   * call} on another thread.
   *
   * @param call object for responding to the remote client.
   * @return listener for processing incoming request messages for {@code call}
   */
  ServerCall.Listener<RequestT> startCall(
      ServerCall<RequestT, ResponseT> call,
      Metadata headers);
}
```

Sadly, different thread context means no exception handling scope, so my answer is not the solution you are looking..

Comment: Sorry , it does not work.  This line `logger.error ("Uncaught exception from grpc service");` is not reached ! I feel strange too.

Comment: Well, interception do occurs but as the documentation states, `next.startCall(call, headers)` immediately returns and get executed in another thread and eventually we loose the stack scope for the exception. Sadly I don't know if any workaround is possible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

On Kotlin adding the try/catch on the listener's methods does not work, for some reason the exceptions are swallowed.

Following the link that @markficket posted, I've implemented a solution creating an implementation of a `SimpleForwardingServerCall`.

```kotlin
class ErrorHandlerServerInterceptor : ServerInterceptor {

    private inner class StatusExceptionHandlingServerCall<ReqT, RespT>(delegate: ServerCall<ReqT, RespT>) 
        : ForwardingServerCall.SimpleForwardingServerCall<ReqT, RespT>(delegate) {

        override fun close(status: Status, trailers: Metadata) {
            status.run {
                when {
                    isOk -> status
                    cause is MyException -> myExceptionHandler(cause as MyException)
                    else -> defaultExceptionHandler(cause)
                }
            }
                .let { super.close(it, trailers) }
        }

        private fun myExceptionHandler(cause: MyException): Status = cause.run { ... }

        private fun defaultExceptionHandler(cause: Throwable?): Status = cause?.run { ... }

    }

    override fun <ReqT : Any, RespT : Any> interceptCall(
        call: ServerCall<ReqT, RespT>,
        metadata: Metadata,
        next: ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT>
    ): ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> =
        next.startCall(StatusExceptionHandlingServerCall(call), metadata)

}
```

Then of course you need to add the interceptor on the server creation

```kotlin
ServerBuilder
  .forPort(port)
  .executor(Dispatchers.IO.asExecutor())
  .addService(service)
  .intercept(ErrorHandlerServerInterceptor())
  .build()
```

And then you can simply throw exceptions on your gRPC methods

```kotlin
override suspend fun someGrpcCall(request: Request): Response {
  ... code ...
  throw NotFoundMyException("Cannot find entity")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used AOP to deal with rpc errors globally, and I find it convenient. I use the AOP in guice, and the way to use it in spring should be similar

1. define a method interceptor

```

```
public class ServerExceptionInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServerExceptionInterceptor.class);

    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        try {
            return  invocation.proceed();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String stackTrace = Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(ex);
            logger.error("##grpc server side error, {}", stackTrace);
            Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
            StreamObserver<?> responseObserver = (StreamObserver<?>)args[1];
            responseObserver.onError(Status.INTERNAL
                    .withDescription(stackTrace)
                    .withCause(ex)
                    .asRuntimeException());

            return null;
        }
    }

    @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE}) @Retention(RUNTIME)
    public @interface WrapError {
        String value() default "";
    }

}
```

```

2. add @WrapError to all rpc method

   `@Override @WrapError
   public void sayHello(HelloRequest req, StreamObserver<HelloReply> responseObserver) {
       HelloReply reply = HelloReply.newBuilder().setMessage("Hello " + req.getName()).build();
       logger.info("#rpc server, sayHello, planId: {}", req.getName());
       if(true) throw new RuntimeException("testing-rpc-error"); //simulate an exception
       responseObserver.onNext(reply);
       responseObserver.onCompleted();
   }`

   3. bind the interceptor in guice module

`ServerExceptionInterceptor interceptor = new ServerExceptionInterceptor();
    requestInjection(interceptor);
    bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(WrapError.class), interceptor);`

4.testing